# CodeIgniter -> URI Class, more specific; uri->uri_string()

Tags: codeigniter, url

with CI, when I do this:

```
var_dump($this->uri->uri_string());

var_dump($this->config->item('base_url'));
```

in controller `all` and method `index()`, I get these outputs:

```
string 'dropbox/derrek/shopredux/afsgasg/sasga' (length=36)

string 'http://localhost/dropbox/derrek/shopRedux/' (length=40)
```

shouldn't `$this->uri->uri_string()` output: afsgasg/sasga?
what have I done wrong?

### **My routes.php config**

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'all/index/$1';

$route['default_controller'] = 'all/index';

$route['404_override'] = '';
```

---

### **My .htaccess in same folder as index.php**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

---

### My config.php config

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

---

if there is further info needed I am happy to supply.

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->uri->uri_string()
```

Returns a string with the complete URI. For example, if this is your full URL:

http://example.com/index.php/news/local/345
The function would return this:

news/local/345

check it out at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

So in your case ::  the url is

```
http://localhost/dropbox/derrek/shopRedux/#something#
```

so it will output `"dropbox/derrek/shopRedux/#something#"`

Comment: dosen't uri_string() take base_url into consideration?

Comment: shouldn't it include localhost then?

Comment: i.e. in my case, I want "http://localhost/dropbox/derrek/shopRedux/"
to be treated the same as www.shopRedux.com/

Comment: in that case you should point your virtual host at that location, means point your virtual host of shopRedux at this location "localhost/dropbox/derrek/shopRedux/"

Comment: are you still facing any issues?

Comment: please excuse my ignorance.
But how come var_dump($this->uri->uri_string()) outputs string '' (length=0) when i only write localhost/dropbox/derrek/shopRedux/ ?